# Plot differences between SVG and PNG output under Cairo

Tags: windows, r, graphics, plot, cairo

I'm trying to create plots that are visually identical (assuming same DPI) using R's Cairo library.  However, PNG and SVG output are markedly different despite identical settings.  I'm running R 2.15.2 on Windows 7.  Example and illustrations follow.

Updated: These look more alike, but are still different.

```
library( Cairo )
library( lattice )
cars_xyplot = xyplot( speed ~ dist, data = cars )
Cairo( file = 'temp.png', type = 'png', dpi = 120, pointsize = 12, bg = "white", units = "mm", width = 100, height = 100 )
plot( cars_xyplot )
dev.off()
Cairo( file = 'temp.svg', type = 'svg', pointsize = 12, bg = "white", units = "mm", width = 100, height = 100 )
plot( cars_xyplot )
dev.off()
```

http://i.minus.com/itsJoNPU2iRZK.svg

http://i.minus.com/ibagje4DmtcA1u.png

Original: Drastic differences

```
library( Cairo )
library( lattice )
cars_xyplot = xyplot( speed ~ dist, data = cars )
Cairo( file = 'temp.png', type = 'png', dpi = 120, pointsize = 12, bg = "white" )
plot( cars_xyplot )
dev.off()
Cairo( file = 'temp.svg', type = 'svg', dpi = 120, pointsize = 12, bg = "white" )
plot( cars_xyplot )
dev.off()
```

http://i.minus.com/ibj8wqtqXsyZqN.svg

http://i.minus.com/ibult36ExZJ75o.png

Comment: (1) Why would you set a dpi for a vector graphic format? (2) The graphs are the same except for the dimensions, for which the defaults are different for the two devices. (2) is clearly shown in the documentation for `?Cairo`.

Comment: (1) Why not?  Or more to the point, why wouldn't Cairo just ignore the setting for SVG?  (It does not.) (2) Fixed in the above example.  Differences remain.

Comment: The point of vector graphics is that they display the same regardless of how you resize them. The whole concept of DPI sort of doesn't apply . If changing the dpi for an SVG does anything, it will only override (or alter) the display size. The only other thing I can think of is that how these sorts of files are displayed isn't just dependent on R (i.e. how they are produced) but also on the graphics devices/viewers on your computer.